# silverlight with WCF(get data through collections)

Tags: wcf, silverlight, collections

in my silverlight page I am fetching the data through WCF
WCF is returning an **BusinessEntityCollection** that is the collection of rows

```
SqlParameter[] sqlParameter = new SqlParameter[]{new SqlParameter("@recordType",recordType)};
                MenuEntity menuEntity;
                MenuEntityCollection menuEntityCollection = new MenuEntityCollection();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(_ConnectionString,CommandType.StoredProcedure, <br>StoredProcedures.GetMenus, sqlParameter))
                {
                    if (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        menuEntity = new MenuEntity();
                        DataAccessHelper.GetEntity(sqlDataReader, menuEntity);
                        menuEntityCollection.Add(menuEntity);
                    }
                }
                return menuEntityCollection;
```

**-->** in silverlight page when I am calling WCF there I am getting an error
MenuEntity menuList = new MenuEntity();
            menuList = e.Result;  **<-----error line**

**error:** Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.**ObservableCollection**' to 'FastTrackSLUI.AdminServiceReference.MenuEntity'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write line [CollectionDataContract] before the MenuEntityCollection Class--

[CollectionDataContract]
    public class MenuEntityCollection : BusinessEntityCollectionBase
    {
        public MenuEntityCollection()
        { 
        }
    }

now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning a collection, but you are treating it as a single instance (`menuList` is typed as `MenuEntity`, not some kind of collection). Is the WCF code generated from the "mex"? It should just work... If that is *your* code, try changing `menuList` to `ObservableCollection<MenuEnity>`. Note that over "mex" / soap / etc you don't get the *real* objects back - you get lightweight proxies. So your custom collection types may have evaporated.

Comment: ya I know thats why I am saying MenuEntityCollection option is not coming in my intellisence.

Comment: hi marc thanks for ur response
now I have collection at silverlight page also

AdminServiceClient proxy = new AdminServiceClient();
            proxy.GetMenusCompleted += new EventHandler<GetMenusCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_GetMenusCompleted);
            proxy.GetMenusAsync();

MenuEntityCollection menuList = new MenuEntityCollection();
            menuList = e.Result;

how can I access records in menuList ?